# Why the first Thread.activeCount() return 1 but another return 2 in my code?

Tags: java

Here is my application:

```
public class NamedThread extends Thread {
    /* This will store name of the thread */

    String name;

    @Override
    public void run() {
//Will store the number of threads
        int count = 0;
        while (count <= 3) {
//Display the number of threads
            System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
//Display the name of the currently running thread
            name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            count++;
            System.out.println(name);
            if (name.equals("Thread1")) {
                System.out.println("Marimba");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Jini");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NamedThread objNamedThread = new NamedThread();
        objNamedThread.setName("Thread1");
//Display the status of the thread, whether alive or not
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isAlive());
        System.out.println(objNamedThread.isAlive());
        /*invokes the start method which in turn will call
         * run and begin thread execution
         */
        objNamedThread.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isAlive());
        System.out.println(objNamedThread.isAlive());
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
true
false
true
true
1
Thread1
Marimba
2
Thread1
Marimba
2
Thread1
Marimba
2
Thread1
Marimba
```

What wrong with my application and why?Thank you!

Comment: `Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in the current thread's thread group and its subgroups.`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis : Oh, it means sometimes the activeCount() method return the incorrect value?

Comment: Kind of, as the _javadoc_ states : `The value returned is only an estimate because the number of threads may change dynamically while this method traverses internal data structures, and might be affected by the presence of certain system threads. This method is intended primarily for debugging and monitoring purposes.`

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis : Thanks!That's very kind of you!

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());

    //doSomething()
}
```

The code above output 2

GC occupies a thread, so you get 2, instead of 1

This function is designed for debugging

If you run on debug mode, you would get 1

Answer (score 0):

InteliJ generates another thread that is called Monitor Ctrl-Break thread.

The following code (took it from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_activecount.htm):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            t.setName("Admin Thread");

            // set thread priority to 1
            t.setPriority(1);

            // prints the current thread
            System.out.println("Thread = " + t);

            int count = Thread.activeCount();
            System.out.println("currently active threads = " + count);

            Thread th[] = new Thread[count];
            // returns the number of threads put into the array
            Thread.enumerate(th);

            // prints active threads
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + th[i]);
        }
    }
```

will generate the following output in inteliJ:

```
Thread = Thread[Admin Thread,1,main]
currently active threads = 2
0: Thread[Admin Thread,1,main]
1: Thread[Monitor Ctrl-Break,5,main]
```

You can run it in debug and notice that this thread isnt created. Therefore, this thread is only added during normal run.

Answer (score 0):

If we print all the threads then we can observe that default thread group is **System** and inside the system, there are different threads and groups like :

```
Group[system:class java.lang.ThreadGroup]
 Reference
  Finalizer
  Signal Dispatcher
  Group[main:class java.lang.ThreadGroup]
     main
     Monitor
  Group[InnocuousThreadGroup:class java.lang.ThreadGroup]
    Common-Cleaner
```

In java code default thread group is main. When we print active thread count then it will give an answer as 2 because the main thread group has two threads main and monitor.